# Qualtrics: Using Javascript to Score Questions Inside a Loop/Merge Block

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I have a multiple choice question (Yes/No) where Yes correlates to a score of 0 and No correlates to a score of 1. I've used the "Recode Values" feature to set Yes to 0 and No to 1. This is inside a loop/merge block, so I cannot use the Scoring feature or Embedded Data/Branching in Survey Flow.

My code currently looks like this:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnPageSubmit(function() {
var answer = jQuery("#"+this.questionId+".q-checked").val();
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('answer', answer);
if(answer = 0)  Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('mmm', '0');
if(answer = 1)  Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('mmm', '1');
});
```

I have also tried:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnPageSubmit(function() {
var answer = this.questionContainer.querySelector(".q-checked").nextElementSibling.innerText;
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('answer', answer);
if(answer = 0)  Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('mmm', '0');
if(answer = 1)  Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('mmm', '1');
});
```

Inside the same block after this question, I have a page break and then two questions with display logic. If they answer Yes/get a score of 0 on the preliminary question, it should display Question A. If they answer No/get a score of 1 on the preliminary question, it should display Question B.

My code seems to set their score to 1 and display Question B no matter if they answer Yes or No to the preliminary question.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

There are three issues with your code. The first is that you are missing a space before .q-checked in your jQuery selector. It should be:

```
var answer = jQuery("#"+this.questionId+" .q-checked").val();
```

The second issue is that the value (choiceid) is not the same thing as the recode. You can either use choiceids (probably 1=Yes and 2=No) or use the Qualtrics JS API to get the recode associated with the value.

The third issue is that your comparisons are incorrect. They should look like:

```
if(answer == "0")
```